# Trying to copy a file from one server to another through shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to copy a file from one server to another. The command I'm using goes like

scp -r username@boxName:[source_path] .

However, I am getting below error while trying to copy:

/tmp/test.file: not found [No such file or directory]

./example.sh[3]: *****@**.**.**:: not found [No such file or directory]

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

first one is the source and the second one is the destination of your local pc

```
scp username@remote_computer:/home/username/file.odt /local/destination/path/
```

Be sure that you are typing the paths correctly and you should run this from your local machine.

You can type

```
pwd
```

to find your current path.

Comment: Thanks rumman0786. Using a .(dot) instead of destination should work too. right? That's what I am not able to figure out.

Comment: @mb47, a dot IS a destination. It's the current directory.

Comment: Yes. then a dot should work instead of the complete destination path. BUT it is not.

Comment: can you type in the whole command that you are typing, I don't think its the .(dot) part that's failing. your error message says it can't find the file or directory(probably from the source)

Comment: scp -r username@boxName:/tmp/test.file . (ofcourse I cannot mention the boxname and username - the command is working fine when I replace the dot with the destination file. and m using it directly from the $)

Answer (score 0):

You are at /usr/home/destinationlocation where file needs to be copied on host2.com

scp user@host1.com:/usr/home/filetobecopied .